# Pure CSS solution to split the content inside one(!) wrapper to two columns

Tags: css

I have a dynamic content inside a wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  // Dynamic content
</div>
```

And what I want is something like this:

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d88VA.png)

Basically, I want to split the one-div content to two columns.

Is there anyway I can do this with pure CSS?

I must support all modern browsers, including IE-10-11 and Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper{
  column-count: 2;
}
```

That should work with IE 10 and up

Answer (score 2):

We can use CSS to do this, there is a property called [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

> The column-count CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrapper">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mi justo, venenatis sit amet iaculis nec, scelerisque eu sapien. Morbi porttitor ornare massa nec venenatis. Aenean a neque metus. Quisque venenatis metus diam, ut interdum magna bibendum ut.
  Aliquam nec orci tincidunt, porttitor orci quis, condimentum ipsum. Morbi sed nunc quam. Aliquam egestas tincidunt diam, quis gravida diam elementum vitae. Morbi venenatis, tortor in efficitur consectetur, lectus metus aliquet arcu, in sagittis lectus
  odio vitae ligula. Quisque luctus dignissim leo vitae commodo. Pellentesque condimentum, lectus eu venenatis ornare, sem tellus consequat diam, id semper urna lectus sed quam. Nulla faucibus sollicitudin lectus a ornare. Donec a venenatis tellus. Proin
  imperdiet fermentum blandit. In sit amet lacinia neque. Phasellus luctus ultrices nulla, eu tempus arcu sodales eu. Pellentesque sit amet lacinia dui, vel gravida est.
</p>
```

The [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count#Browser_compatibility) is actually very good too, supporting  IE 10+ and every other major browser.

[image: support table]

Comment: Thank you! 
Just out of curiosity: is there any alternatives to it for ie9, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>  /// Your dynamic DIV
  <div class="column"></div>  /// your dynamic DIV
</div>
```